# What are the reasons that soap has so different smell and flavour?

Tags: senses, nose

Everybody has tried to taste soap in their childhood. One would think that if soap has a tasty smell it would have tasty flavor too. But we know it is not true (in the common cases). But why is there is difference in the senses to our noses and tongues for the same soap?

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding your question. Do you mean: "How is it possible for soap to *smell* tasty, but not *be* tasty?", or more generally: "why is our instinctive of guess of how a substance will taste, given how it smells, not perfect"?

Comment: Exactly, you understand.

Comment: I like the taste of soap :) I retracted my close-vote, but I think the question is quite opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible for a substance to not smell very much, but to *taste* very strongly - chili peppers are a great example. They (in my experience) have a rather weak spicy odor, but the taste is much much more intense. In the case of soaps, very small amounts of [essential oils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_oil) are used to give soaps their odors. You may be able to slightly taste them were you to eat some of the soap (definitely NOT recommended!), but the major taste you'd experience is the actual soap - the [saponified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saponification) surfactants that do the cleaning.